Spock Mock not updating the fields
Suppose we have a class that we want to mock.
class Apple {
 Color color
 bool isFresh
}

We mock it with Mock. We execute the code we need to test. Mocked Apple object gets its Color color updated. However, the field stays null.
// test class
Apple apple = Mock(Apple.class)

myService.myMethod(apple)

assert apple.color == Color.RED //FAIL because apple.color == null 

// tested code of myMethod(Apple apple) 
apple.color = Color.RED


Why use a mock? For the example you give, you should just use an actual Apple

Also, keep in mind that apple.color executes apple.setColor() method on a mock, and thus it won't have any effect.

Tim and Szymon are both right. When using a mock, you should not be surprised to get mock results, i.e. null.
I understand that to unit-test MyService in isolation, you want to mock Apple. But then, please verify an interaction on the setter rather than implicitly calling the getter and expecting a non-null result.
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q78458317

import spock.lang.Specification

import java.awt.*

class MyServiceTest extends Specification {
  def test() {
    given:
    def myService = new MyService()
    Apple apple = Mock(Apple)

    when:
    myService.myMethod(apple)

    then:
    1 * apple.setColor(Color.RED)
  }
}

class Apple {
  Color color
  boolean isFresh
}

class MyService {
  void myMethod(Apple apple) {
    apple.color = Color.RED
  }
}

Try it in the Groovy Web Console.
